# center pictures within containers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to work out the best way for me to center each of my pictures (#contact1, #contact2, #contact3) inside each of their containers. I have tried to put margin left etc but doesnt work for when I scale up.
I have a JSFiddle I have started: http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3592/

HTML:

```
<div class="slide" style="height:66px;">
    <div class="staff staff-matt" data-hammer="[object Object]">
        <div id="contact1"><img src="mobile_aboutus.svg" alt="About us" style="width:44px;height:auto"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="staff staff-shail" data-hammer="[object Object]">
        <div id="contact2"><img src="mobile_aboutus.svg" alt="About us" style="width:44px;height:auto"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="staff staff-leah" data-hammer="[object Object]">
        <div id="contact3"><img src="mobile_aboutus.svg" alt="About us" style="width:44px;height:auto"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS: (View all on JSFiddle)

```
#contact1, #contact2, #contact3{
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:66px;
}
```

Comment: `.staff{text-align:center;}` for horizontally.

Comment: Great, this worked, im a little confused why it would be a text-align:center when its an image...?

Comment: `<img>` is considered as inline block element, like inline element such as `<span>` you can simply center them by setting `text-align:center` on the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

This makes your image have an equal margin on both sides, and usually works with most divs and images.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make you images display block and add margin 0 auto to it

```
#contact1 img, #contact2 img, #contact3 img{
    margin: 0px auto;
    display:block;
}
```